# External hard drive that always used to mount read-write when plugged in now mounts read-only

Tags: mount, drive, read-only

I have an external hard drive that I use for backing up data.  I bought and configured it several years ago, and since then it has always mounted read-write whenever I plug it in.  Recently, though, it's started mounting as read-only.  I haven't knowingly changed any relevant configuration.

Using my limited sysadmin skills, I can unmount the drive from a terminal and then run `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/myusername/Backup`, its usual mount point, and it comes back mounted read-write.

Earlier today the read-only mounting happened again when I plugged in the drive, and I noticed that the drive had been mounted on the directory `/media/myusername/Backup1`, a directory that doesn't normally exist.  When I unmounted the drive, that directory disappeared.

Any tips on how to diagnose the issue and/or restore the original mount-read-write behavior?

Comment: No constructive criticism, downvoter?

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` (`^C` to exit) as you plug in the drive,

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried waltinator's suggested approach of running `journalctl --follow` before plugging in my drive, which was for some reason offered as a comment and not as an answer I could accept.  Within the output I saw the line

```
warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
```

So, I ran `e2fsck` on the drive.  It found some errors and fixed them, and now my drive mounts read-write when I plug it in.  Hurrah!

It would be interesting to work out why I can still mount the damaged filesystem read-write from the command line, but I'll stop here and count myself fortunate to have taken only a minor hit to my reputation for asking a question that is, apparently, ill-posed and poorly-formatted.

Comment: I see someone took the time to find and downvote a six-year-old question of mine.  What an odd community.